# Set "min-width:100%" for images larger than 400px? JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am trying to set up a JS/jQuery/CSS solution to select images larger than 400px and set them to be the full width of the container (`min-width: 100%`).

However, it should not apply to images smaller than 400px to avoid selecting really small ones or thumbnails. Normally, I'd just use classes, but the markup is generated by an old wiki intranet system which doesn't give users the ability to set classes.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.container img {
  border: solid 1px green;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100?text=Should_be_full_width" />
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "no classes" do you mean that you can't use the jquery function 'addClass'?

Comment: It's taking the size of the .container . Make .container full size and the image will follow.

Comment: @JohnSims No, just that they won't be in the original generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').each((i, img) => {
    let width = parseInt($(img).css('width'));
    if (width > 400) {
      $(img).css('width', '100%');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.container img {
  border: solid 1px green;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100?text=Should_be_full_width" />
</div>
```

Comment: This only runs when your images are already cached. The `$(function() {` code runs on `DOMContentLoaded` which happens before images are loaded, so the width will always be 0 and the styling will never be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) property after the images are loaded (*use the window `load` event*) and manually add a class (*use `classList`*).

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for (let image of images) {
    if (image.naturalWidth >= 400) {
      image.classList.add('full-width');
      // or set the style directly if you have to
      // image.style.minWidth = '100%';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.container img {
  border: solid 1px green;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.full-width {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100?text=Should_be_full_width" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
var images = $("img")

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].width >= 400) {
    images[i].style.minWidth = "100%";
  }
}
```

Comment: no need for jQuery :) `images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName